# Error: relation "node_checkpoints" does not exist

Tags: corda

I have a node on Azure with Postgres configured. So far no problems, but last night I left the vm running, but in the morning I see an error keeps popping up, and the node couldn't start up.

Seems like node went down and had a checkpoint/SQL issue, maybe the node tried to restart arbitrarily from checkpoint but failed? Any ideas?

```
[INFO ] 2018-05-08T14:45:16,049Z [Thread-484 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - SUBMITTING {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=cff452a3-ef1a-4817-b2a0-e5e5e0c7b8f9, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T14:45:16.049Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[WARN ] 2018-05-08T14:45:17,088Z [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[ERROR] 2018-05-08T14:45:17,089Z [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - ERROR: relation "node_checkpoints" does not exist
  Position: 13 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[INFO ] 2018-05-08T14:45:17,089Z [Node thread-1] internal.AbstractBatchImpl.release - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[ERROR] 2018-05-08T14:45:17,090Z [Node thread-1] internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[INFO ] 2018-05-08T14:46:10,386Z [Thread-484 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - SUBMITTING {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=ff8d3770-3b55-47af-915b-8d960b56961a, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T14:46:10.386Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[WARN ] 2018-05-08T14:46:10,410Z [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[ERROR] 2018-05-08T14:46:10,411Z [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - ERROR: relation "node_checkpoints" does not exist
  Position: 13 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[INFO ] 2018-05-08T14:46:10,411Z [Node thread-1] internal.AbstractBatchImpl.release - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
[ERROR] 2018-05-08T14:46:10,411Z [Node thread-1] internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=Org1, O=Org, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2028af36-c801-4f29-a187-887078fef025, invocation_timestamp=2018-05-08T13:02:53.985Z, session_id=b39ca52a-cc49-4bcb-8e95-f8708f0a721e, session_timestamp=2018-05-07T07:13:11.155Z}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unknown issue. Can you raise it here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues?